# Resource not found Exception SwipeRefreshLayout ProgressBackground

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am getting resource not found exception

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffff0000
```

when doing this :

```
swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

While I have this in colors.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

I use R from my project (not android.R)

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Any ideas to fix this ?

Comment: Check if you imported the correct R, if so try to clean the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of the `setProgressBackgroundColor` method should be a color resource ID and not an integer representing a color. Use it like this:

```
swipeLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
```

Comment: Android Studio says Methods that take a color in the form of an integer should be passed an RGB triple, not the actual color resource id. You must call getResources.getColor(resource). But the application is running with swipeRefresh red background now.

Comment: I guess that this was an error by the Google team that worked on the support library. Annotations that provide "type checking" for integer parameters were recently introduced and it seems that the method parameter is incorrectly annotated. If you haven't done this already, try updating the support library to the latest version (21.0.3)

Comment: Problem still remains check my gradle.

Comment: Does the code compile now? Is there an warning? Does the app have an red background? I guess that the only thing that you can really do is to wait for an update that fixes this issue.